# Как обработать telegram webhook node js?

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

Использую telebot, код что то такое:

```
const TeleBot = require('telebot');
const bot = new TeleBot({
    token: 'TOKEN', // Required. Telegram Bot API token.
    webhook: { // Optional. Use webhook instead of polling.
        url: 'https://vm1945277.nvme.had.yt', // Обычная VDS машина, .
        host: 'localhost', // Webhook server host.
        port: 443, // Server port.
        maxConnections: 40 // Optional. Maximum allowed number of simultaneous HTTPS connections to the webhook for update delivery
    }
});
bot.on('text', (msg) => msg.reply.text(msg.text));
bot.start();
```

Я не знаю что передать в url и в host, помогите пожалуйста простым языком.

Comment: Webhook - это одна из опций телеграма. Она отправит http запрос на ваш сервер, когда произойдёт какое-либо обновление. Вы уверены, что вам это нужно?
https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks

Comment: Ну как бы да, мне нужно запустить этот скрипт, что бы понять что я делаю не так, потом в основном скрипте решить эту проблему, что бы он работал.

Comment: Webhook не единственный способ получения уведомлений. Если вы делаете это локально на своём ПК, то скорее всего имеете закрытые порты. Тогда webhook вам не подходит =)

Comment: Я делаю это на VDS.

Comment: А подскажите пожалуйста в чём сейчас заключается ошибка и что не работает?

Comment: Как можно проверить на убунту открыты ли порты?

Comment: Проблема в том, что этот код почему-то не работает...

Comment: Я выше ссылку кидал, там очень много способов, которые описывают как это можно сделать. Только учтите что открытых портов мало, кроме открытого порта должен быть слушатель этого порта

Comment: И вы уверены что ваше соединение защищено и вы используете SSL/TLS? Если нет то telegram не будет вам ничего отправлять

Comment: Да, стоит сертификат от летсенкрипт. На url'e ошибка 502, может ли это влиять на работоспособность? Только что заметил

Comment: 502 ошибка означает, что слушатель является прокси-сервером и ему некуда передать этот запрос либо слушатель, которому он должен передать это письмо не отвечает. Проще говоря кто должен принимать сообщения от телеграма?

Comment: Эмм, ну... Не знаю :C

Comment: Добавил ответ ниже

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не работал с этим фреймворком, но почитав документацию думаю, что вы должны сделать следующее:

1. Установите nginx/apache или любой другой веб-сервер, установите для него ssl сертификат. В конфигурации укажите, что он должен слушать 443 порт используя ssl сертификат и передавать запросы в локальную сеть, на любой порт, например `5000`
2. В JS коде укажите в качестве url `https://<ваш_домен>:443`. Host оставьте `localhost`. Порт будет тот, который вы выбрали в первом пункте (например `5000`).

После этого ваше приложение должно получать сообщения от телеграм

**Upd:** Возможно вам проще будет использовать метод `getUpdates`. Тогда вам не нужен веб-сервер и ssl сертификат, кроме того он работает быстрее

Comment: Я прошу прощения, как именно в конфигурации указать 443 порт?

Comment: @Corry какой вы веб-сервер используете?

Comment: apache2 получается

Comment: @Corry с apache к сожалению не могу подсказать, всегда использую nginx =)

Comment: Не проблема! Мне не принципиально, не работал ни с тем, ни с тем)

Comment: У вас есть ssl сертификат в формате <any_name>.crt и приватный ключ в формате <any_name>.key?

Comment: Нету. Я читал, что можно самопис создать, не знаете как?

Comment: @Corry можно, но разве у вас нет готового? Вообще вот здесь достаточно подробно описано как установить сертификат на nginx: https://www.reg.ru/support/ssl-sertifikaty/ustanovka-ssl-sertifikata/ustanovka-ssl-sertifikata-na-nginx Для передачи соединений в nginx используется алиас proxy_pass Про него почитать и примеры посмотреть тут можно: https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass

Comment: В том то и суть, что хостинг предоставляет мне сертификат, а .crt и .key не дает. В поддержку постучал, жду ответ

Comment: @Corry мало кто даёт готовые сертификаты, часто дают несколько файлов и надо собирать самому, как? Описано выше

Comment: Сертификат на VDS поставил, теперь пытаюсь разобраться с proxy_pass но не выходит, можете немного подробнее описать процесс создания слушателя? простите что задалбываю вопросами, просто это ну очень срочно(

Comment: @Corry вот здесь есть примеры, эти примеры должны находиться в внутри блока `server` где вы указывали ssl https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/ В качестве location вам нужно использовать `/`. это говорит, что нужно перенаправлять запросы по любому пути

Comment: Не знаю как это сказать, но мы не настраивали ССЛ в настройках nginx, мы поставили его через панель. Если я вас правильно понял, мне нужно прописать `location ~ \ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
}`
В http {
}
Я верно все понял?

Comment: Не в `http`, а в `server` и без `~`, т.е. `location /`. Я не знаю как nginx и telegram отреагируют на отсутствие ssl, это зависит от вашего провайдера. Не совсем понятно кто и каким образом отдаёт ssl

Comment: Елки-палки, все равно не работает ;c
Вот константы bot.js:
`const host = 'localhost';
const port = 5000;
const url = 'https://vm1945277.nvme.had.yt:443';
`
Вот nginx:
`    server {
        location \ {
            proxy_pass https://localhost:5000;
        }
    }`
может я таки ошибся гдето?(

Comment: @Corry укажите nginx'у куда писать логи и посмотрите получает ли он вообще запросы

Comment: Можете снова помочь немного?)) Как указать место логирования?